# What is the source of proxy list ip addresses

Tags: proxy

There are websites that provide proxy lists like
http://hidemyass.com/ or http://letushide.com/ and Im sure there are a lot more, so the question is from where they take that ip addresses ?
If I make a search by them it shows some company or website/domain, and I do not think that company/website would allow to use their ip address, Or I am getting it wrong ? so how it is done ?

The second question is: is that possible that someone can use my website's IP address as a proxy to make a query. And if the answer is positive, can I prevent that somehow? Im on a shared hosting.

Thanks